# Update Wordpress data from external DB

Tags: wordpress

Wordpress update post information  with  data from another database, is it possible update in realtime? Is it possible with API? 
another case, how I can update my events in wordpress with external calendar? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which calendar you are using. if you are using google calendar, you can integrate it using this plugin:
https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/google-calendar-events/
Otherwise can you please more specific about which calendar you are using. and yes it is possible to update some information from another database in realtime through API.